# How to organise the html to render the page in 3 parts?

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to render my pages by rendering

1. The header
2. The body

The problem is, when i render the both parts, the body is not wraped into the `.content` div, here is some code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="content">

      <script type="text/template" id="header-template">
        <div>navbar</div>
      </script>
      <div id='header-container'></div>

      <script type="text/template" id="body-template">
        <p>Welcome !</p> <!-- Is not wraped inte the #content div -->
      </script>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With backone i just do:

```
hearder.render();
body.render();
```

Thanks !

Comment: What does your `render` function look like?

Comment: Also you're not closing your content `div` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is completely mangled: your template has an unclosed `<div>`, but there is a unmatched `</div>` close tag on the page. It looks like you're attempting some kind of `document.write` style templating, where the first template opens a tag and a later template closes it. I wouldn't recommend it. Look at the [Backbone.View documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View) on how to render the view to a certain element.

Basically you should have the container elements in the DOM:

```
<div id="header-container"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer-container"></div>
```

And then render the view **into** that element:

```
body.render({el:"#content"});
```

Or:

```
body.render();
$("#content").html(body.el);
```

I  bet if you fix these, it might work a bit better.

Comment: Ok thanks, but in this case how to use divs which has to wrap many templates ? For exemple the bootstrap divs for responsive scaffolding: `<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>` here the first div wrap 2 different templates (or maybe i don't build my views with the good logic).

Comment: @Ludo, I'm not sure I follow you 100%, but here's a tip: One view must have one root element. You can either solve this by having multiple views (sidebar and body) or one view which renders the container (the root element being the container) and then renders some templates into two elements within it.

Comment: yes my explanation was a little bit confused. I want to use multiple views (sidebar + body in this example), but i don't know how to manage the div `container-fluid` which wrap the both. Because what i saw by doing some tests is, the html is generated before the rendering of the templates, so the templates are rendering after the html (so we can't render a template into a div by declaring it into this same div, it will be display after it)